# ASP.NET use Hyperlinks instead of Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to add a **Logout** link to my form so our employees can log out of the job they are working on.

The code behind in my application is simple:

```
protected void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   MasterPage.Logout();
}
```

A `asp.Button` I can code by wiring up the `onClick` event.

How would I call this method using a `asp.Hyperlink` control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `LinkButton` control.  That gets rendered as an `a` tag, and the page will be posted back to itself so that your `OnClick` function can be invoked.

Comment: Only [conditionally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx): _The LinkButton control renders JavaScript to the client browser. The client browser must have JavaScript enabled for this control to function properly._

Comment: Yeah, that's how pretty much all the web forms controls work, they use JavaScript and hidden fields, and post a form that's on every page. Web forms are pretty lame like that.

Comment: Well, not quite, since any _real_ button will submit the form.

Comment: I think he means all server controls need to use javascript, which is correct to me.

Comment: @maxisam The `Button` is a server-side control, yet isn't _reliant_ on script.

Comment: well, if you turn off auto post back, it doesn't rely on JS. However, if you use asp.net, 99% you need JS . I don't see the point why we waste time here to argue it.

Comment: @maxisam An argument implies there is any debate on the issue: there is no "auto post back" [sic] for `Button`, and no script gets attached to it on render.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. Button doesn't use dopostback since its type is submit. Thanks for reminding me tho.

Answer (score 2):

The `Hyperlink` control renders a simple hyperlink, which won't allow you to wire it up to a click handler. Try the [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) control instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace Hyperlink with LinkButton.
Hyperlink has no server side events.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One thing I might suggest is to simply use CSS to *style* your actual-fact button to adopt the *look* of a link, as opposed to imitating a button from something that will likely be styled differently anyway.

When imitating a button, you are [relying on the user having script enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) in their browser:

> The LinkButton control renders JavaScript to the client browser. The
>   client browser must have JavaScript enabled for this control to
>   function properly.

Whereas a button that is a button will submit the form.

EDIT:

As per your comment, here is a quick example you could easily adapt:

CSS:

```
.hyperLinkButton
{
    border:none;
    background:none;
    color:Navy;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.hyperLinkButton:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Mark-up:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="hyperLinkButton" 
  Text="Is it a HyperLink? Is it a LinkButton? No, it's a Button!" />
```

Comment: If you have a link to some info on using CSS to style an *actual-fact of a button to impersonate the look of a link*, I'd very much like to see it. It may be what I end up going with.